# How do you resolve the error "unexpected '_592_000'" while setting up CodeIgniter 4.2?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I got the below error when trying to set up CodeIgniter 4.2

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '_592_000' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test1\app\Config\Constants.php on line 41
```

I didn't change anything on `Constants.php`.

Comment: At the very least you need to post the line of code that threw that parse error

Answer (score 3):

##### Error:

```bash
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '_592_000' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test1\app\Config\Constants.php on line 41
```

##### Explanation:

You're receiving the error above because the file `app\Config\Constants.php` uses Numeric literal separators.

[Excerpt from `app\Config\Constants.php`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/fdc4e92f80cb0c2e9953a4b8e0e87e3996e4c4bc/app/Config/Constants.php#L41):

```php
defined('MONTH')  || define('MONTH', 2_592_000);
defined('YEAR')   || define('YEAR', 31_536_000);
defined('DECADE') || define('DECADE', 315_360_000);
```

[Numeric literal separators were once proposed as a feature using RFCs](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/numeric_literal_separator) on 2019-05-15.

> The human eye is not optimized for quickly parsing long sequences of
> digits. Thus, a lack of visual separators makes it take longer to read
> and debug code, and can lead to unintended mistakes.

The [numeric literal separator feature was later implemented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.numeric-literal-separator) in `PHP 7.4`.

> Numeric literals can contain underscores between digits.

Based on the contents of [CodeIgniter `v4.2.0`'s `composer.json` file](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/v4.2.0/composer.json), it's clear that you're **required** to have installed `PHP 7.4` and above on your computer for it to run smoothly.

> ```json
>     "require": {
>         "php": "^7.4 || ^8.0",
>     }
> ```

##### Solution:

Make sure you're running `PHP v7.4` and above.

---

###### Addendum:

If you don't know how to check your current PHP version, open your terminal or command prompt and run the command `php --version`:

```bash
$ php --version
PHP 8.1.3 (cli) (built: Feb 16 2022 08:20:53) (NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the '_'

```
defined('MONTH')  || define('MONTH', 2592000);
defined('YEAR')   || define('YEAR', 31536000);
defined('DECADE') || define('DECADE', 315360000);
```